# Check if 1-x is completely Monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

I had a question about how can I check whether $f(x)=1-x$ is completely monotonic. Could somebody provide a simple example based on this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions), a completely monotonic function must satisty $$ (-1)^n \frac {d^n}{dt^n}f(t)\ge0$$ for all nonnegative $n$ and $t>0$; the special case $n=0$ reduces to requiring  $f$ non-negative on $(0,\infty)$.  Which your $f$ clearly does not satisfy.

The characterization of completely monotone functions as Laplace transforms of non-negative measures is also a tip-off: if $x=2$, say, you would be representing $-1$ as the integral of a non-negative function.

Comment: Thanks @kimchi lover. But the above function satisfies $ ( - 1 ) ^ { n } \frac { d ^ { n } } { d t ^ { n } } f ( t ) \geq 0 $:  $(-1)f'(x) = -1 (-1) =1\geq0$, $(-1)^2f''(x)=(-1)^2\cdot0 =0 \geq0$ etc.

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks @kimchi lover, this explanation is much more clear!